# Print out User Avatar from User ID in Buddypress

Tags: buddypress

So I have the User Id of someone in Buddypress.

What is the function to print out their Avatar?

What is the function to link to their profile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will display the user avatar by user ID and also make the avatar a clickable link to their profile.

```
<?php $member_id = bp_core_get_userid( '1' ) ?>

<a href="<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id ) ?>" 

title="<?php echo bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member ) ?>">

<?php echo bp_core_fetch_avatar ( array( 'item_id' => $member_id, 'type' => 'full' ) ) ?></a>
```

Obviously replace the number in the first line with the userID that you want.

Comment: Thanks for this! FYI - The bp_core_get_userid() function accepts the username as the parameter and returns the user_id. Also, for those copying and pasting this code, fix the bp_core_get_user_displayname to accept $member_id as the argument, not $member.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use `bp_activity_avatar()` function:

```
<?php bp_activity_avatar(array('user_id' => $user_id)); ?>
```

Comment: is it safe usage? 
I tried to use it and i got warning:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
"\wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-activity\bp-activity-template.php"
— Coz the (global $activities_template) variable is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

Output the avatar of the user for specified User ID

```
 bp_activity_avatar( 'user_id=' . $user_id );
```

Returns a HTML formatted link for a user with the user's full name as the link text for specified User ID

```
 echo bp_core_get_userlink(  $user_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed do it with code like this (without php warnings):

```
$imgTagAva = apply_filters( 'bp_group_request_user_avatar_thumb', bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $user_id, 'type' => 'thumb', 'alt' => sprintf( __( 'Profile picture of %s', 'buddypress' ), bp_core_get_user_displayname( $user_id ) ) ) ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

found it. The best solution is below:

```
get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'), 40);
// OR
get_avatar($author_id_or_email, $size);
```

Comment: Found... where? I see that code [in previous posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get_avatar%28get_the_author_meta%28%27ID%27%29%2C+is%3Aa). Be sure to [give proper attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).